# .NET - How to Publish asp.net web service APIs to Goddady web hosting

Tags: mysql, asp.net, api, service, hosting

I'm building a RESTful asp.net Web API application. And it's work as well on my local and the VPS. And I tried publish my service to web hosting such as Goddady web hosting.

I'm already edit connection string in both Webconfig and Appconfig files and add more code into Webconfig file such as `DbProviderFactories`in `<system.data>` tag and `<add namespace="MySql.Data"/> <add namespace="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>` in `<page>` tag to help access to Mysql database from web service app and copy all files in publish folder to httpdocs folder of web hosting.

But when I trying to connect to any API via Postman. I got Files Not Found 404 error.

Have someone ever deployed asp.net web APIs to web hosting ? could you kindly guide me how to publish asp.net APIs to web hosting ?

Thanks for advance !

Comment: You just need to upload all your files via FTP to your root folder. Please make sure you have setup your correct default page

Comment: Thank so much for your reply @MarkSpencer. I've setup successfully my asp.net service on web hosting. I can access the default page on web browser. 
But when I test APIs via Postman tool, I got an "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" which fired by system. I've debugged on my local to find exception detail in inner exception but everything work as well
I don't know why I got this error on web hosting.
Do you have any idea for this problem
Thank you

Comment: Not too sure. Have you contact your hosting provider? Please ask them to check the error logs on the server.